# Cant catch exeptions with urllib2

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, urllib2

I have a script printing out the response from an API, but I cant seem to catch any exceptions. I think I've gone thru every question asked on this topic without any luck.

How can I check if the script will catch any errors/exceptions?

I'm testing the script on a site i know returns 403 Forbidden, but it does'nt show.

My script:

```
import urllib2

url_se = 'http://www.example.com'

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'API to File')]

try:
    request = opener.open(url_se)
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print  e.code
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    print e.args
except Exception:
    import traceback
    print 'Generic exception ' + traceback.format_exc()

response = request.read()                            
print response
```

Is this the right approach? Whats the best practice for catching exeptions concerning

```
urllib2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in your program. If any exception occurs in try block then variable `request` becomes `undefined` in `response = request.text()` block.
Correct it as

```
import urllib2

url_se = 'http://www.example.com'

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'API to File')]

try:
    request = opener.open(url_se)
    response = request.read()                            
    print response
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print  e.code
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    print e.args
except Exception as e:
    import traceback
    print 'Generic exception ' + traceback.format_exc()
```

Test it on your machine you will surely see the Exceptions.
Catching exceptions individually only make sense if you are doing something specify with them otherwise if you only want to log the exceptions then a universal `except` block will do the job.

Comment: Hm. For some reason the site im testing on shows a lot of information in my script, but 403 forbidden in the browser. Anyways, the second question, is this the right approach/good practice? should I catch more exceptions?

Comment: @TheDude the prime reason of catching Exception is to stop unfavorable circumstances from breaking your code. This is good practice to follow but. It doesn't make sense catching each Exception individually like the way you are doing, since you aren't doing some specific with those exceptions.